# Stacked bar plot, percentage of entire bar and the total value

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have made quite a lot of progress of where I want to be, but there is still some fixes to be made. What I have right now as an image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GwsEcvx.png]

However, as we can see, the percentage are all relative to the Ref, which has 100%. Looking at the second bar (x-axis 4), we have 64.2+1.6+20.6 = 86.4 != 100. Additional to that, preferably the total time of all the stacks should show up above it. A rough sketch of what I'm thinking:

[image]

File data.txt:

```
one,two,three,four
Ref,0.0,194.228732386,0.0
4,40.0069652252,3.1391023845,124.752030532
8,31.416268219,4.0078951455,111.883188346
9,76.8558069667,3.9906615645,112.515372569
11,82.992369082,4.38474317025,112.11896845
13,81.5133020117,4.27987078675,116.598416893
16,81.5851874813,8.44496483425,117.332427258
```

Latex file:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{data.txt}\mydata

\makeatletter

% To allow the 'Ref' x-axis entry
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/flexible xticklabels from table/.code n args={3}{%
        \pgfplotstableread[#3]{#1}\coordinate@table
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumn{#2}\of{\coordinate@table}\to\pgfplots@xticklabels
        \let\pgfplots@xticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@x
    }
}

% For calculating the percentage
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.5.1,
    percentage ticks/.code={
        \pgfplotsset{
            xtick pos=left,
            axis x line*=left,
            xlabel=Units,
            nodes near coords={
                \pgfkeys{
                    /pgf/fpu=true,  % PGFplots uses floating points internally
                    /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed
                }
                \pgfmathparse{100*\pgfplotspointmeta/\pgfplots@axiswide@metamax}
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%
            },
            every node near coord/.append style={yshift=1ex}
        }
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
/pgf/number format/precision=1,
compat=newest, %Better label placement
ybar stacked,
width=1.2\textwidth,
height=0.4\textheight,
enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.2},
ymin=0,
enlarge x limits = 0.2,
bar width=32pt,
title={Instance els19 with 1\% max error},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=0},
ylabel={Time in milisseconds},
xtick=data,
flexible xticklabels from table={data.txt}{one}{col sep=comma},
xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
nodes near coords,
axis lines*=left,
cycle list={
    {fill=black!30,draw=black!30},
    {fill=black!20,draw=black!20},
    {fill=black!10,draw=black!10}
},
axis on top,
major grid style=white,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={draw=none,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}},
percentage ticks
]
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y=two]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y=three]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y=four]{\mydata};
\legend{Best 1\%,Average 1\%,Worst 1\%}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have a feeling that the most interesting row is the:

```
\pgfmathparse{100*\pgfplotspointmeta/\pgfplots@axiswide@metamax}
```

However, I've looked through the manual for quite some time unable to find a suitable macro for the "current" bar.

Any help/pointers at all are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

As people have upvoted this, I figured I would respond with my solution:

I extended the data field with a sum, which was possible in my case. I believe you can also do this by creating a temporary table with \pgfplotstable as well.

```
% Showing the sum on top
\pgfplotsset{
        show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \pgfkeys{
                    /pgf/fpu=true,  % PGFplots uses floating points internally
                    /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed
                }
                \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xidx{\pgfmathresult}
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\xidx}{sum}\of{\mydata}
                \let\yval\pgfplotsretval
                \node[
                    at={(normalized axis cs:%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                            \yval)%
                    },
                    anchor=south,
                ]
                {
                    \pgfmathprintnumber{\yval}
                };
            },
        },
    }

\pgfplotsset{
    percentage ticks/.code={
        \pgfplotsset{
            nodes near coords={
                \pgfkeys{
                    /pgf/fpu=true,  % PGFplots uses floating points internally
                    /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed
                    %/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=2
                }
                \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xidx{\pgfmathresult}
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\xidx}{sum}\of{\mydata}
                \pgfmathparse{100*\pgfplotspointmeta/\pgfplotsretval}
                \let\percent\pgfmathresult
                \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\percent pt=100 pt}}{
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=0]{\percent}\%
                }{
                    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\percent pt<10 pt}}{
                        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\percent}\%
                    }{
                        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=1]{\percent}\%
                    }
                }
            },
            every node near coord/.append style={yshift=1.2ex,xshift=-1.7ex,font=\footnotesize} %anchor=west,xshift=-7.2ex}
        }
    }
}

\begin{axis} [
    xtick=data,
    flexible xticklabels from table={data.txt}{gran}{col sep=comma},
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
    nodes near coords,
    percentage ticks
]
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y=two]{\mydata};
    \addplot [show sum on top] table[x expr=\coordindex, y=three]{\mydata}; % Note that "show sum on top" should be applied to the plot which always is different from 0
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y=four]{\mydata};
    \legend{Prefetch, Execute, Optimized}
\end{axis}
```

I'm afraid this is not a very minimal working example, but it shows the ideas:

Calculating the percentage by getting the x index, which is then used to find the sum in the table, and then taking the y-value of the node divided by the sum.

Adding the sum atop the bar is somewhat alike. For one item in each x-axis (I choose the "two" plot, cause that is the one  which always has non-zero values), you simply create a node with the (x=x, y=sum value) coordinates. Apparantly zero-values are ignored and I am not sure how to deal with that. Worth noting as well is that I only modified the snippets, as they are originally from other threads here on tex SE.